# How to convert Flink DataSet tuple to one column

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I've a graph data like

```
1 2
1 4
4 1
4 2
4 3
3 2
2 3
```

But I couldn't find a way to convert it a one column dataset like

```
1
2
1
4
4
1
...
```

here is my code, I used scala ListBuffer, but couldn't find a way doing it in Flink DataSet

```scala
    val params: ParameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    env.getConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params)
    val text = env.readTextFile(params.get("input"))
    val tupleText = text.map { line =>
      val arr = line.split(" ")
      (arr(0), arr(1))
    }

    var x: Seq[(String, String)] = tupleText.collect()
    var tempList = new ListBuffer[String]
    x.foreach(line => {
      tempList += line._1
      tempList += line._2
    })

    tempList.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `flatMap`:

```scala
// get some input
val input: DataSet[(Int, Int)] = env.fromElements((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))

// emit every tuple element as own record
val output: DataSet[Int] = input.flatMap( (t, out) => {
  out.collect(t._1)
  out.collect(t._2)
})

// print result
output.print()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, by the way, do I need to specify type for output and out variables? Compiler gave error when I didn't write like `tupleText.flatMap( (t, out: Collector[String]) => {... `  
I haven't figure out yet when I need to gave type of variable and when scala can identify/find proper type itself

Comment: Did you declare the result type of `output`? You need either `output: DataSet[Int]` or `out: Collector[Int]`. Otherwise the compiler cannot infer the result type.